# Pass in values from webpage as search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with a bunch of buttons, free input boxes, number of miles from the zip code that the user can populate in order to search for specific locations. 
I need to take all the values from the user's inputs and pass it along to a post API call which will return a result set based on the user's search criteria. I need to pass the search criteria to the post API in the following format

```
{
  "text": "string",
  "criteria": [
    "string"
  ],
  "count": 0
}
```

The text value is coming from a free input text box.
The criteria are coming from a list of buttons that are selected/highlighted by the user and the number of miles together with the zip code.
the count value is coming from a choice of 3 buttons that have predefined numbers 250, 400, 550.

For now, I hardcoded the search values below, but I need guidance on how to make this dynamic by taking the values the user inputs on the page.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api/id',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "text": "parks",
    "criteria": ["string"],
    "count": 0
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you provide the form you're working with ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from an `<input>` by assigning it an id, then using the jQuery selector to fetch its current value. For example, an input with `type=text` or `type=number` can have its value fetched with `$("#id").val()`. The check boxes that you have can have their current state checked with `$("#id").prop('checked').` Then, you can use an if statement to determine the count value:

```
let count;
if($("#250-button").prop('checked')) {
    count = 250;
} else if($("400-button").prop('checked)) {
    count = 400;
} else {
    count = 550;
}
```